# Using customer.subscription.update instead of invoice.paid and invoice.payment_failed event webhooks to handle Stripe Subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to build a simple Subscriptions website with three or four different plans using Stripe.

In the application when a user registers, a Stripe Customer ID is assigned. Then, when subscribing to a plan, I'm listening to these webhook events:

`customer.subscription.updated || customer.subscription.created`

They are triggered every time there's a change in the subscription. Then I check the `status` property which will tell me if the user is `active`, `incomplete`, `trialing`, `canceled`, `past_due`, or `unpaid` and act accordingly in my database table for users.

This makes sense to me, but Stripe uses invoice event webhooks instead (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#provision-and-monitor):

- checkout.session.completed
- invoice.paid
- invoice.payment_failed

Should I listen to these events instead? I'm not sure, because, for example, invoice events won't track when a customer changes the plan in the middle of a billing cycle, so I'd have to add the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really up to you and what your integration needs (there are a lot of different webhook events, and many of them can be used for the same purpose). Typically, users care more about knowing when the renewal invoice is actually paid which is why that guide recommends those events as the bare minimum. If you had a subscription where you were sending goods to a customer every month it makes more sense to listen for confirmation of successful invoice payment before shipment.

That being said, you definitely can rely on `customer.subscription.updated` events but you'll need to also listen for the `invoice.paid/payment_failed` events if you care about knowing when payment succeeds or want to notified of retries.
Take the situation where your subscription renews and payment is successful:

1. First, you'll get the `customer.subscription.updated` event signaling that the billing cycle has changed and a draft invoice has been created (this will also send an `invoice.created` event).
2. After an hour the invoice is finalized and paid automatically
3. Your webhook endpoint gets an `invoice.paid` webhook event, but not another `customer.subscription.updated` event because the status was active and has not changed.

Comment: For some SaaS applications where nothing changes if subscription stays `active` and invoicing emails are handled by Stripe, it's okay to rely on `customer.subscription.updated` event only.

Comment: One problem with relying only on `customer.subscription.updated` is that it doesn't contain the customer's email address. If that's something you need and you don't want to make a second query using customer ID, then you'd have to listen to `invoice.paid` or `invoice.payment_succeeded`.